# window.location.replace is not working on client side

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, client-side

I have a javascript function on my jsp page.

```
function gt()
{
     var e=document.getElementById("ParentType");
     var val=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
     window.location.replace("iba1?value="+val);
}
```

I have created wizard for some functionality.The above code works fine in my machine,but if I test the same thing on client browser it is giving error like URL not available.

At the same time if I give whole location of jsp means it is working in client side but not in my machine.I've added path of jsp like this

```
window.location.replace("netmarkets/jsp/actionitem/iba1.jsp?value="+val);
```

Why this happening?Some Ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving it the whole path? The URL will not work probably because it is a relative path on the server side.

Comment: well if that is the relative path that is working fine on client side..but not on server side

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. Put the whole path like this window.location.replace("http://[YOURSITENAME]/netmarkets/jsp/actionitem/iba1.jsp?value="+val);

Comment: I embed this with windchill.Normally we don't need to specify the whole path.All jsp's in windchill are under that netmarkets folder.So it'll directly take from there.If your solution is for client side means read my question again.And I tried this not working on server side also.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be working if the Client Deployment & your development machine have different deployment structure.